# How to fix AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden; request: HEAD

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, databricks, amazon-iam

Why am I getting:

AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden; request: HEAD https://my-bucket.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com some_folder/part-00001-tid-4355744669774358191-8bcd5132-03de-4047-83a5-51757d8a717a-21-1-c000.csv

When I try to write to S3 from apache spark/ databricks?

Reading from this (and other buckets) works fine. Only writing fails.

The S3 permissions look like this:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
            ],
            "Sid": ""
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
            "Sid": ""
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

How can this be fixed?

- Spark is writing files to the bucket.
- But it fails for some:

  - The part files are being written
  - and the _started files as well
  - but somehow the rename/delete for the _success seems to fail if I am reading this correctly.

Comment: The only similar reference I could find is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469801/403-forbidden-error-on-s3-rest-api-head-request but that is referring to broken signatures. Given the fact that I am using Databricks I would expect that should not be a software issue on how the signatures are created.

Comment: Try moving `"s3:GetObject"` to the 2nd statement instead of the 1st one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `s3:*Object` actions should have the `/*` at the end of the resource (unless the resource ARN points to a specific bucket).
So, as @Ermiya Eskandar said, moving the `"s3:GetObject"` to the last statement should fix the problem.

Comment: Interestng - as when I moved the /* up to be present for both clauses none of the clauses neither the list worked anymore. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Indeed, adding the statement to both seems to fix the issue

Comment: You moved the `/*` to the first statement and it didn't work? But you left there this one `"arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"`, right?

Comment: yes - but keeping both works